# unittest unable to import class from pickle (AttributeError: Can't get attribute...)

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, python-3.6, python-unittest

I need a unittest to load a previously saved class in a pickle. However, when I load the pickle in the unittest (out of unittest works), it raises the error:

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Foo' on <module
> 'unittest.**main**' from '...\unittest\**main**.py'>

Code example to save the class (I save this code in `run_and_save_class.py`):

```
from pickle import dump
from pickle import load
from pickle import HIGHEST_PROTOCOL

class Foo(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = None
        self.file_out = "./out.pkl"

    def save_class(self):
        with open(self.file_out, "wb") as file_out:
            dump(self, file_out, protocol=HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
            
    def load_class(self):
        with open(self.file_out, "rb") as file_out:
            cls = load(file_out)
        return cls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cls = Foo()
    cls.bar = "saving a bar"
    cls.save_class()
```

Code to test the class (I save this code in `unittest_class.py`):

```
import unittest
from run_and_save_class import Foo


class ClassValidation(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("init")
        self.cls = Foo
        self.instance = Foo().load_class()
        print("class loaded")
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def test_anything(self):
        pass
```

I run in Anaconda Prompt:

```
python run_and_save_class.py

python -m unittest -v unittest_class.py
```

The latter is the one that raises the error.

However, this works in a notebook.

```
from run_and_save_class import Foo
cls = Foo().load_class()
```

I don't understand why it doesn't in a unittest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that pickle saves the object relative to `__main__`, where `dump` was called (via `save_class`). To load the same object, you have to provide the same environment - a workaround is to add the class to `__main__` in your test, so that pickle can find it:

```py
import __main__

class ClassValidation(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        __main__.Foo = Foo
        self.cls = Foo
        self.instance = Foo().load_class()
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def test_anything(self):
        self.assertEqual("saving a bar", self.instance.bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to instanciate the Foo object in the ClassValidation in this way : self.cls = Foo()

Comment: That line would work, but not the line where I load the pickled class: `self.instance = self.cls.load_model()`