# Can't use pickled function inside a pytest test

Tags: python, pytest, pickle

So I have this scenario, I create a `function` that depends on `pandas`, which I then `pickle` and then reload and try to run and gives `error` that `pd is not defined`:

```
def pandize(arg):
    pd.DataFrame('a')

import dill
with open('pandize.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(pandize, f)

with open('pandize.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    p = dill.load(f)

p(1)
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

After that I `import pandas as pd` and the code gets called.

But I can't replicate this behaviour inside a `pytest` test function. Even if I add the `import pandas as pd` I'm still getting the `NameError` `pd is not defined`. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm not sure if `dill` behaves the same, but `pickle` saves the object relative to the current module, that may change if called from pytest. Check out if your problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63827918/12480730).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen i guess that is the reason for failing, but still trying to grasp how this thing works, any good resource to understand this behaviour?

Comment: I don't have any specific resources available, but you can find a hint [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) at the end of the chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by **@MrBeanBremen** in linked question in the comment, importing `__main__` and then defining `pandas` in `__main__` made the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import __main__
__main__.pd = pd

with open('pandize.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    p = dill.load(f)

p(1)
```

This setup doesn't cause the test to fail with a `NameError` any more.

Comment: You just saved me. This should be upvoted to heaven.