# import __main__ with pickles

Tags: python, pickle

Can someone explain me what is the role of `import __main__` in python? I read a similar question but could not understand it. (this in general first)

Then in particular, when a pickle of an object is made in a script from within a  `if __name__ == "__main__":` , and I try to read it from another script I have to use `import __main__` in order to avoid the error

```
 AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'theObject' on <module '__main__'
```

as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65318623/4451521) (In the answer I understand *why* the error is happening but not why the import main solves it)

Comment: "In the answer I understand why the error is happening but not why the import main solves it" - then this should instead be a comment on that answer, requesting further clarification.

Comment: If only I wanted to understand that answer, yes, but I ask because I want to understand what `import __main__` does, not only for that particular case

Comment: It... looks for a module that is named `__main__`, and imports it, just like any other `import` statement. And the picked object is in the context of a module with that name, because... it was pickled inside an `if` statement, that explicitly checks to make sure of that.